# flask change jinja2 variable content in a template and display the new content

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I don't know how dumb my problem is, but I really couldn't figure out how to solve it

So, I have a html page that is rendered by flask, the page contains a variable {{ log }} (string) that is initially empty.

```
@app.route('/some-roote')
def function(id,log='some string'):
    return render_template('webpage.html',log= log)
```

When the page is rendered initially, everything works fine, ('some string' is displayed in the UI)

At some point of my execution, I would like to change the content of {{ log }} and display the new content to the user.

I tried doing:

```
logs = new content;
render_template('webpage.html',log= logs)
```

but nothing happened, literally, the string value doesn't change, the webpage doesn't refresh, and I don't get any errors...

Please help guys. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did the page reloaded?

Comment: nope, nothing happened

Comment: Flask normally picks up on edits to the script and restarts itself, but it may be worth killing the script & restarting it.

Comment: Is this both tested in same route, imean url ?

Comment: @itzmeontv yes the same route

Comment: Did you reload the page in the browser? It sounds like you were expecting that to happen automatically when `flask` reloaded the script. I don't think thats the case.

Comment: when i reload the page from the user, I got the initial empty "log". 
Also, I would like to change the content without the interaction of the user (i.e without clicking or reloading anything).

Comment: isn't there a way to access the jinja2 variable from python?? I mean forcing the change of its content without having to reload the page or anything

Comment: No, it cannot update there using jinja, because variable is rendering already in the backend(python).To update use `javascript` or `jquery`

Comment: can I invoke a jquery function via python?

Comment: @MahmoudKsemtini I am also looking to solve the same problem you are having. Did you figure out a solution yet?

Answer (score 4):

Jinja2 templates cannot change a page without the browser refreshing, they are simply a way for you to place dynamic content on a page before sending it to the browser. To change your page while on the client's browser you'll need to use javascript.

You can perform an ajax call from the browser back to your server, which then the server can send back the updated log variable. However, you'll then need to use javascript again to update that text on the DOM.

The best library for this is jQuery. You can also use frameworks like AngularJS and EmberJS that help you with data binding (among many other things).

You'll have to branch out into javascript for this kind of interactivity. Unfortunately, Python does not run natively in the browser.

Comment: I am aware that the proper way to fix this is via JS (jQuery), but the thing is, that jQuery is **single threaded**, and I already have an ajax call running by the time that I like to change the variable content  (the ajax call takes a long time ~ 10 sec). And that's why I tried to change the variable using Python

Comment: The wonderful thing about javascript is that it can be non-blocking. Utilize call backs and make another ajax call.

Comment: what do you mean by non-blocking? can it handle asynchronous  calls?